# Methods declared must return void (not float)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I'm attempting to return two float values, width and height using a standard UIButton function. I added the "-> Float" but I am greeted with this error. If I change it to "-> Void" then I am left with Unexpected non-void return value in void function. What am i doing wrong here?

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonValue: UIButton!
@IBAction func smallB(_ sender: Any) -> Float {

    var inital = 2
    let divisble = 2

    var width: Float
    var height: Float



    if inital % divisble == 0
    {
        width = 0.14
        height = 0.07
        buttonValue.titleLabel?.text = "Big"
        inital + 1
    }
    else
    {
        width = 0.28
        height = 0.14
        buttonValue.titleLabel?.text = "Small"
        inital + 1
    }

    return width
    return height

}
```

Comment: To whom do you want to return a value?

Comment: a global variable

Comment: You do not return to variables, you return to code. You can assign values to variables. This is done with the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: if you need to return multiple values then you can use tuples!

Comment: I need to return width and height, haha. How would tuples be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBAction function can be invoked/called by user interaction on any UIElements like Button, Switch, Segment Controller. And its response (return type) goes back to user interface element, you may not get float values in your code, if your use IBAction and attach that action to your Interface Builder

Remove return type from your `IBAction` method, if you've connected method with your Interface Builder Button element. It would be meaningless for you to return value, if your action is generated from IBOutlet element.

```
@IBAction func smallB(_ sender: Any) {
   // action contents

   // also remove following return statements
   // return width
   //  return height
}
```

But if you really want to return height & width (two float values) as response to this function call then you should  call it programmatically, and change function declaration like:

```
func smallBTest(_ sender: Any) -> CGSize {
   // action contents

  //Update your return statement like
  return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

let size: CGSize = smallBTest(<button instance > buttonValue)
print("Size: Width = \(size.width)  -- Height = \(size.Height)")

// or you can try this as well
@IBAction func smallB(_ sender: Any) {
  let size: CGSize = smallBTest(sender)
   print("Size: Width = \(size.width)  -- Height = \(size.Height)")
}
```

Comment: Now I have the "Unexpected non-void return value in void function" next to return width and height.

Comment: remove return width , return height from your IBAction

Comment: I am just adding comment for jonpeter , as per his question he return width & height from IBAction.So he need to remove this part from his IBAction method.Your answer is fine.However you can also use tuple instead of CGSize.

Comment: I apologize for the last response. What is the difference between the action contents in the smallB func and the smallBTest func?

Comment: @jonpeter IBAction is a function which can be invoked/called by user interaction on any UIelements like Button, Switch, Segment Controller. And its response (return type) goes back to user interface element, you may not get float values in your code, if your use IBAction and attach that action to your Interface Builder

Comment: @jonpeter If want float values as response (return type) of your function call then you must call it programatically, Try last option I've added in my answer and see. Let me know if you will face other issue rather than your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return value from IBAction method. So change your method as

```
@IBAction func smallB(_ sender: Any) {
 // your logic
}
```

And remove `return width`, `return height` .

If you want to use width and height make them as global variables.

Comment: I did but would you explain how the global variable values would be updated in the function?

Comment: @jonpeter what issue. Have you removed your return statements of `return width, return height `. Explain the issue